# The Germans words for "resolve" that carry the context of resolving conflict in social interactions

Tags: english-to-german

During my research when I was attempting to interpret "resolve conflicts quickly" I found a few words that indicate resolving.

The translation that I previously had was `Konflikte zu lösen schnell`

But I was not sure if `lösen` was the best fit because though it seemed to be a direct translation, it seems to be more related to physical actions.

`bereinigen` seems like a good fit because it seems to indicate settling conflict in a context related to social interaction.

`beschließen` also seemed like a fit because it seems to indicate deciding on something.

However so far the one that seems to fit the most is `aufklären` because it seems to mean to "clear up"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first attempt is closest, but you got the word order wrong. Standing by itself (as a headline etc.) it would be:

> Konflikte schnell lösen

Depending on context, it may be embedded in a sentence like:

> Mit diplomatischem Geschick gelang es ihr, die Konflikte schnell zu lösen.

An alternative is the word *[beilegen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beilegen)*, which can also be used to express the resolution of all kinds of disputes:

> Der Konflikt konnte glücklicherweise schnell beigelegt werden.

or

> Das Ziel besteht darin, den Konflikt möglichst rasch beizulegen.

Your other options don’t really work with *Konflikt,* but they might be used in related situations:

*Bereinigen* can be used with *Situation, Lage* or more generally with anything that needs to be cleansed/purged of something to be put into its proper state.

> Durch das entschlossene Eingreifen der Polizei konnte die Situation rasch bereinigt werden.

*Beschließen* means (as you correctly noted) to decide or to agree on something, as in:

> Die Regierungen beider Länder beschlossen in dem Abkommen, den Konflikt beizulegen.

*Aufklären* is used in the context of solving crimes or revealing something not known to all participants, e.g.:

> In den Gesprächen konnten einige Missverständnisse zwischen den beteiligten Parteien aufgeklärt werden.

Comment: Note that "beilegen" should only be used in passive form (as in the the two examples), or in active form when the subject is the conflicting parties (as in the example for "beschließen"). It cannot be used to describe an external actor resolving a conflict (as implied in the first example for "lösen").

Answer (score 3):

I'd opt for `lösen`. Generally there are very few things you can do with a `Konflikt` anyway: You can `ihn lösen` (resolve it) or you can `ihn beenden` (end it). `bereinigen`, `beschließen` and `aufklären` do not really work with `Konflikt`.

There are several contexts of `lösen` where it has no relation to physical things:

- Ein Problem lösen. (Solve a problem)
- Eine Aufgabe lösen. (Solve a problem/finish a task)
- Sich von jemandem lösen (Distance oneself from someone)
- (innere) Spannungen lösen (Dissipate (inner) tensions)

So don't hesitate to apply `lösen` to `Konflikt`!

Comment: +1 für die Erwähnung der einfachsten Alternative - an **beenden** habe ich nicht gedacht.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `beschließen`: This does not fit, it means decide, not resolve.

I guess this is a problem with these funny prefixes: you could say `den Konflikt schließen` (close the conflict), but it's rather unusual. Germans would say `den Konflikt beenden`, as mentioned before.

Comment: **Schließen** does not work with **Konflikt**. It implies closing, joining or completing something. It may be used for ending something (like a conference or a meeting - see **Eröffnen** and **(Ab-)Schließen**), but these terms are not used for conflicts.

Comment: @Hulk: that's what I say above.